# How to make nested forms work in different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, nested-forms

I am new to programming and Rails, and I'm working on the sign-up process for an app I'm working on. I have both `user` and `profile` models. As part of the sign-up process I'm mixing fields for both `user` and `profile`, so I'm using nested forms.

I'm trying to get the nested forms to work in a controller that handles my static pages, because I want to initiate the signup process on the home page.

The sign-up process can be initiated two ways: Directly from the homepage or skipped on the homepage and initiated at a /signup/skip view.

My InfoController (where the `home.html.erb` file with the form exists):

```
def home
  if logged_in?
    redirect_to current_user.profile
  end
end
```

Nested form in `home.html.erb`:

```
<%= form_for(:profile, :url => 'signup', :html => {:id => 'homepage'}) do |f| %>
  <p class="hometext">I'm&nbsp;</p>
  <div>
    <%= f.label :first_name, :placeholder => 'First name' %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name, :size=> 8, :id => "profile[first_name]" %>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="profile[last_name]">Last name</label>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name, :size=> 8, :id => "profile[last_name]" %>
  </div>
  <%= f.fields_for :user do |f| %>
  <p class="hometext">.&nbsp;My&nbsp;email&nbsp;is&nbsp;
    <div>
      <label for="user[email]">Email</label>
      <%= f.text_field :email, :size=> 13, :id => "user[email]" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <p class="hometext">.&nbsp;I want to&nbsp;</p>
  <div>
    <label for="user[stat]">put stat here</label>
    <%= f.text_field :stat, :size=> 13, :id => "user[stat]" %>
  </div>
  <p class="hometext">when I grow up.&nbsp;</p>
  <div id="button">
    <%= submit_tag 'Join', :class => 'button orange' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Profile Model:

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :first_name, :last_name ...
  belongs_to :user
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end
```

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :password, :email
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

For some reason, when I enter data in the form I am redirected to /login, which is in `Routes.rb` as `Sessions#new`. So here's SessionsController:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    if user = User.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to user.profile, :notice => "Logged in successfully"
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "Invalid login/password. Try again!"
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

And last but not least the ProfilesController:

```
class ProfilesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @profile = Profile.new
  end

  def create
    @profile = Profile.new(params[:profile])
    if @profile.save
      redirect_to profile_path, :notice => 'User successfully added.'
    else
      render :action => 'new'
    end
  end
```

From the server:

```
Started POST "/signup" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Aug 27 10:36:50 -0400 2011
DEPRECATION WARNING: You are using the old router DSL which will be removed in Rails     3.1. Please check how to update your routes file at:     http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/. (called from /Users/me/Desktop/app/config/routes.rb:1)
  Processing by ProfilesController#new as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Join", "profile"=>{"last_name"=>"...", "user"=>  {"test"=>"...", "email"=>"..."}, "first_name"=>"..."}, "authenticity_token"=>"u82Jom5PV+5BeTLZ5qQENxQiY1lcyFiXR4aNC7NR+5g=", "utf8"=>"\342\234\223"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/login 
Completed 302 Found in 35ms


Started GET "/login" for 127.0.0.1 at Sat Aug 27 10:36:51 -0400 2011
  Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
Rendered layouts/_header_out.html.erb (0.5ms)
Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (2.2ms)
Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (32.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 40ms (Views: 39.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

**Update: Routes file (the relevant parts at least) below:**

```
match '/login' => "sessions#new", :as => "login"
match '/signup', :to => 'profiles#new'
match 'skip/signup', :to => 'info#signupskip'
match 'skip/profiles/new', :to => 'profiles#newskip'
root :to => 'info#home'
resources :users
resources :profiles
resources :info
```

Can anyone help me figure this out? Any recommendations on how to get it working and do it according to best practices would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post your routes.rb?

Also, have you looked at Devise for this? Seems you might be trying to reinvent the wheel.

Check it out..

http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise

Comment: I put the relevant parts of Routes.rb in the question. I haven't checked out Devise but I will! Thanks.

Comment: Devise looks good but I'm curious as to how to make things work without it. Any insight would be appreciated!